# Как узнать по строкам, что пути до файлов одинаковые?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть два свойства со строкой в качестве значения. Строка это путь в файловой системе. 
Пример -

```
var strOne = './dir_1/dir_2/dir_3'; // это полный путь
var strTwo = 'dir_2/dir_3'; // это сокращённый путь
```

Как при таком положении узнать, что пути эдентичные? У меня все мысли ломаются, когда появляется вариант вот таким путем -

```
'dir_2/dir'
```

Объясню задачу подробнее - есть директория с вложенными папками и файлами. И есть файл, в котором все пути записаны. И вот мне приходит строка и мне нужно проверить, есть ли она в файле со всеми путями....

**Добавлено:**
Изначально заданно свойство "исключение" из обработки файловой системы, ссылающиеся на директорию -

```
var settings = { exception: './dir_1/dir_2/dir_3' };
```

Сразу замечу, что путь может быть написан по разному -

```
var settings = { exception: './dir_1/dir_2/dir_3' };
var settings = { exception: 'dir_1/dir_2/dir_3' };
var settings = { exception: './dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/' };
var settings = { exception: 'dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/' };
```

Далее я получаю адресс файла и мне нужно узнать пренадлижит ли он этой директории -

```
'dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/dir_4/file.extension'
```

Вот... И дальше я сопостовлял строку и определял, входит файл в исключенную директорию или нет. Но как уже выше сказал, появилась возможность ошибки.

Но мне не сложно добавить свойство с базовой директорией, от которой будут происходить все измерения.

Comment: Если есть возможность (все происходит на одном сервере), то вместо путей я бы хранил `i-node` последних в пути каталогов.

При сравненнии же, брал  i-node каталога с заданным файлом (системный вызов `stat`) и просто смотрел, есть ли такой среди хранимых i-node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

хм, ну я предположу что можно сделать два массива и сравнить их
К примеру:

```
var arr1 = strOne.split('/').splice(2)
    , arr2 = strTwo.split('/')
    , check = arraysEqual(arr1, arr2);

function arraysEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a == null || b == null) return false;
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

 alert(check); // TRUE

// Проверять надо так, если не поняли
arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) // равно TRUE
```

Comment: @webphp: я немного не понял Вашего ответа... Но спрошу тогда только у Вас - по Вашему './dir_1/dir_2/dir_3' === 'dir_2/dir_3' ?

Comment: Да равно. Код выше это доказывает
http://jsfiddle.net/de9Uq/

Comment: Ну функцию всегда можно изменить, если не подходит удаление с первого элемента массива, делайте так
1. Подсчитайте сколько элементов во втором массиве
2. Удаляйте из первого массива (Пункт 1) с конца второго массива.

Тогда уж 100% проблем не будет, даже если в первом массиве миллион значений xD

На счет регулярок не в курсе, у самого с ними туговато. А уж написать такую регулярку я точно не смогу.

Comment: Это будет некорректно работать, ровно потому что вопрос некорректен. Как вообще можно утверждать, что два пути ведут на один и тот же файл, только если не проверить. Либо надо уточнить что пути бывают относительными и нам дана база

Comment: @donkey: немного дописал.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить *абсолютный путь к файлу* и сравнить его с имеющейся у вас информацией.

Примеров куча, как в Apache Commons, так и в других кастомных библиотеках. В Java есть **java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()**, но работает с объектом File, а не со строкой.